# ImageProcessing MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have a video of a welding procedure, and for every frame I need to take all the contours of the welded area, and detect all the edges.
Unfortunately, the images I got aren't the best quality, I tried to put several filters and make image enhacement and it didn't work to take the sharp edges.

Image Below:

[image]

I managed to make the following code, but the results were terrible.

```
clc

clear all

vid = VideoReader('home/simulation/V6_008.avi');

h=ones(3,3)/9;

for i=1 : mov.NumberOfFrames

thisframe = read(vid,i);

g = image(thisframe);

lsave = sprintf('image.jpg');

saveas(g, lsave, 'jpg')

a = imread(lsave);

a1 = imcrop(a,[150 450 650 300]);

a2= imsharpen(a1,'Radius',50,'Amount',500);

b = rgb2gray(a2);

c=imadjust(b,[0.6 0.8],[]);

c1= imfilter(c,h);

c2=adapthisteq(c1,'cliplimit',0.01,'Distribution','exponential');

d = edge(c1,'canny',0.1);

e=bwareaopen(d,50);

imshow(e) end
```

these Filters and image enhacements helped a little bit, but it is still not enought for my measurements.

So I have 2 questions:

1) Do you know any other tool I can use to make my edge detection cleaner? I just want to outline the specified region as you can see.

2)  I need to make the edge detection for every frame, and then save all the frames, and also save the video after edge detection. I don't really know how to do it. Do you?

Thanks very much guys, I apology if it was confusing.
I'm afraid if I don't finish this properly I gonna get very troubled.. :(.
Thanks again, I apreciate any help!

This is the edges I would Ideally have after edge detection:

[image]

Comment: your data looks very difficult. I cannot even tell what region you want to segment. Can you make up an image in gimp/paint/photoshop with the results you would ideally get?

Comment: Hi, 

I made it on paint which edges I would Ideally get from this frame. 

I added on the post.
Its important that I get the sharp edges because I gonna have to measure them in further steps.

Thanks Again for your help, I hope it was clear enough!

Comment: I guess with a couple of hundreds of thousands of dolars and 2 or 3 PhDs there is a way of getting an good answer to this... Maybe. Its just too general, too hard. I would recommend to start with background subtraction techniques. by the way, 2) is not a question. It has no the (?) thingy. Whats you problem there? `imwrite`?

Comment: question 2) I need to make the edge detection for every frame, and then save all the frames, and also save the video after edge detection.
I don't really know how to do it. Do you?

Comment: Would it be possible to just work on a subset of the image? I suppose if you apply your image enhancement techniques on an area that is more restricted to the area of interest, they would work better. Have you tried increasing the contrast? Histogram stretching would be a very basic tool for that.

Comment: I tried to crop the image and then work on it, It had no effect for the quality.

Also, I tried different ways increasing the contrast, it works very well to visualize the area of interest, but after applying edge detection(canny, prewitt...) it looks like it had no effect.

Comment: I think there are plenty of edge detecting algorithms on Mathworks, maybe you are better-off looking for some help there.

Comment: You might also try looking at http://opencv.org/, a well-known open-source image processing library (albeit in C++, not MATLAB).

Comment: what I would try to at least is a simple background subtraction as said above: load as many frames as possible in a 3D matrix (intensity values only, 3rd dimension for time) and let apply the `median` function along the 3rd axis. Take this as background model and subtract it from all the frames. If you are lucky much of the background remains stable and the region you want to subtract is what changes at most. Also have a look at morphological operations to remove these dark spots if they are still present after background subtraction, and adaptive contrast enhancement.

Comment: Another approach would be using machine learning: Segment random frames of different videos by hand as you did before in paint. Use a unique colour like green. Then extract patches along the lines in Matlab at positive patches and random patches of the same images that are not on a line as negative patches. Extract image features, like HOG or LBP from these patches and train a classifier. Use the trained model on each pixel in the image and use graph based optimization to find the optimal single edge as boundary. Also try spatial and temporal regularization, to clean the noisy classification.

Comment: this may not be of much use if you have to use your current images, but one option for the future is to light the welds from the side. Similar to how they light surfboards when sanding them http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Slideshows/_production/ss-100730-surfboards/ss-100730-surfboards-01.grid-8x2.jpg. If the light is at the same height as the surface any bumps (welds) will cast shadows which will be much easier to detect as opposed to having top lighting. I think its always better to start with a good image, it reduces computation later

Comment: @Junior. I trained a neural network to learn the pattern of the area you want to isolate. I took blocks of data centered in a pixel that is either _in_ or _out_ of the region you marked as your _region of interest_. So, the network learn that if a pixel has neighbors with that pattern, it will mark that pixel as `1`, else as `0`. The output of the neural network after learning the pattern [is this](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~rivas_perea/ys/result.png). Then you can simply use `Sobel` to get the [edges of the result](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~rivas_perea/ys/area.png), which is the area you want.

Comment: @Junior. [This image](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~rivas_perea/ys/overlay.png) would be the overlay of the result, which is more or less what you want, I think.

Comment: OMG, @PabloRivas, this is the Ideal result I want! How did you do this? I never worked on neural networks, so I don't know how it works. Was it on matlab?
Do you think it's possible to apply the same methode for all the frames?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Junior
It is very hard to say if it will work for _everything_, but it should perform decently if you send me another frame, I can see if it will work or not pablorp80 at gmail dot com. But yes, neural networks are part of Matlab and they are very easy to use, but a little harder to explain. Matlab has several tutorials that are extremely useful.