# Imageprocessing on neural networks

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, video-processing

I have a video of a welding process, and for each frame I need to detect the edges of the welded area for further measure this area.
The problem is that the quality of the video is poor, so I can't detect the edges of the frames through normal methodes, image enhacement doesn't work either.

I posted this question before here on Stackoverflow, and one guy managed to enhance my area of interest through NEURAL NETWORKS.

I need to select the area as following (Paint outlined).

[image]

This guy who managed to make it, he gave me the following explanation:

'''''''I trained a neural network to learn the pattern of the area you want to isolate. I took blocks of data centered in a pixel that is either in or out of the region you marked as your region of interest. So, the network learn that if a pixel has neighbors with that pattern, it will mark that pixel as 1, else as 0. The output of the neural network after learning the pattern is [this](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~rivas_perea/ys/result.png). Then you can simply use Sobel to get the [edges of the result](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~rivas_perea/ys/area.png), which is the area you want.'''''''''

So this is the exact result, as described, that I want.
But I don't know at all how to work with neural networks, either how to do this.

Does someone know it ?

If someone know how to measure the area of my outlined area for each frame (a code for the whole video) I would appreciate very much.

Thank you very much guys.

This is the link of the original question_ [ImageProcessing MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565860/imageprocessing-matlab)

Comment: What differentiates the area you want highlighted from the other areas? Is it always the area that looks sort of static-y? You'll need a set of different images to train your network on so you need to define what makes the outlined area different.

Comment: @Daniel this is the non-outlined area i.stack.imgur.com/0CzHk.jpg, 
We can tell the difference from the welded area.

Answer (score 0):

After detecting edges using sobel or canny, you can use the countour method from openCV to detect the boundary of the ROI. Then you can use the areacountour method to calculate the area bounded by that countour

You can extract each frame from the video into independent images